# What's $(\langle 0|\otimes I)(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)$ simplified?

Tags: linear-algebra

It's a rather simple question. I think I am confused by the fact that using $\langle0|$ on a qubit doesn't result in another qubit. So I'm not sure if I should interpret $\langle 0|$ as the $1\times2$ matrix $(1 \space 0)$.

Comment: Do you mean $(\langle0|\otimes I)(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)$?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. The notation is still uncommon for me.

Comment: I strongly advise reading (and accepting) hft's answer. Learning how to deal with abstract representation is way more useful generally speaking than writing down the matrix representation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's $(\langle 0|\otimes I)(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)$ simplified?

As an alternative to Tristan's very good and explicit answer in terms of the matrix representation, it might be easier/illuminating to work directly with the operator/bra/ket expression.

By *definition* of the direct product, and remembering, for example, that $|00\rangle$ really means $|0\rangle\otimes|0\rangle$, we have:
$$
(\langle 0|\otimes I)(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)
=(\langle 0|\otimes I)(|0\rangle\otimes|0\rangle)
+(\langle 0|\otimes I)(|1\rangle\otimes|1\rangle)
$$
$$
=(\langle 0|0\rangle\otimes I|0\rangle)
+(\langle 0|1\rangle\otimes I|1\rangle)
$$
$$
=1|0\rangle + 0|1\rangle = |0\rangle
$$

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $|0\rangle$ is the vector $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$, and $\langle0|$ is the conjugate transpose of $|0\rangle$. Thus, $\langle0|$ is the row vector $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\end{pmatrix}$. We can then compute:
$$\begin{align}
\langle|0|\otimes I &= \begin{pmatrix}1&0\end{pmatrix}\otimes\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$$
You can then compute the product with $|00\rangle+|11\rangle=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$:
$$(\langle 0|\otimes I)(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=|0\rangle.$$